# how to compare values in a R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to work with the below data frame and what I am trying to do is to compare the values from columns:

```
#create a sample data frame
df<-data.frame(
item=c("a","b","c","d"),

price_today=c(1,2,3,4,5),

price_yesterday=c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

If values from column price_today are the same compared with values from column price_yesterday, then print okay or else print not okay, and the printed result will be shown as a new variable in the data frame.

May I know how should I go about the ifelse part here?

Many thanks for your help and have a good day.

Modified Questions:

Hi all, so now what if the df becomes like this:

```
#create a sample data frame (modified) 
df<-data.frame(
item=c("a","a","c","d"),

price_today=c(1,"",3,"XYZ",5),

price_yesterday=c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Now it contains both blank value and non-numerical values in column price_today. And instead of a,b,c,d in column item, it becomes a,a,c,d in column item. I have been trying to do the following:

1. Sort column item by "a" and I have the below code:

> df_1<-df[df$item=="a",]

2. After df_1 is filtered, then again sort price_today, by removing blank and non-numerical values with codes below:

> df_1<-df[!is.numeric(df_1$price_today),]

I am able to filter out by "a" in column item, however, with the second filter, it then returns with the original df, may I know what did I do wrong here?

Million thanks for your help and have a good day/night.

Comment: `df$new_var <- ifelse(price_today == price_yesterday, 'okay', 'not okay')` ?

Comment: Thanks Axeman, working perfectly now!